# Normal disjunctive and conjuctive form from a truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

Let's say that we get a table with zeros and ones. We need to get it into disjunctive normal form or conjuctive normal form. We also have discrete variables $x_1,..,x_n$ that are either $1$ or $0$. How do you determine where to put negation and where not to put it.

for instance: we have a row: $$p = 0, q= 1, r = 0, \quad \text{table row result = 1}$$

Should I write this as: $$...\vee(\neg p \wedge q \wedge \neg r) \vee ...$$
or $$...\wedge(\neg p \vee q \vee \neg r) \wedge ...$$

What is the correct way ? What if the table row result would be zero?

Or the other way with negations? So my question is how do we know where the negations are?

Comment: Please write an *informative* title—one that describes (in part) the content of your question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I edited the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are looking for a DNF, you focus on all rows where the table result is a $1$, and you generate a conjunction for that row exactly the way you did, and than you disjunct together all those conjunctions into one big disjunction.

On the other hand, when looking for a CNF, you focus on all the rows where the result is a $0$, and now you generate a disjunction that is equivalent to the negation of the conjunction you would have gotten normally. That is, if with your example of $p =0, q=1, r=0$ and table result $=0$, you would create the term $p \lor \neg q \lor r$. Finally, conjunct together all those disjunctions to get the CNF

Example:

\begin{array}{cc|c}
p &q&f(p,q)\\
\hline
1&1&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&0\\
\end{array}

DNF: focus on rows 1 and 3, and that gives you $(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \land q)$

CNF: focus on rows 2 and 4, and now you get $(\neg p \lor q) \land (p \lor q)$

Comment: And if it helps: the DNF form says "the variables match either row 1 or row 3". The CNF says "the variables don't match row 2 and don't match row 4".